# React-Native Horizontal Scrollview not working but works well with vertical

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react-native. I want to achieve a horizontal scrolling of list.     When added horizontal the scrolls won't work. But it works well went removed `horizontal={true}`.
Below is the code.

```
       <View style={styles.headerMargin} >
           <ScrollView
            
            horizontal={true}
           style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15 }}
            
            contentContainerStyle={{
              justifyContent:
                this.state.typeofCountry.length > 2
                  ? 'flex-start'
                  : 'center',
              width: '100%',}}
             >
                
            {this.state.typeofCountry.map((item, i) => {
              return (
              
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignContent: 'center',
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    
                  }}>
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.textBlacRegular,
                      { marginLeft: i == 0 ? 0 : 10 },
                    ]}>
                    {item.label}
                  </Text>
                  <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Image
                      style={{
                        width: 30,
                        height: 18,
                        marginLeft: 10,
                        marginRight:20,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                      }}
                      source={item.icon}></Image>
                     
                  </View>
                  
                </View>
                
                
              );
            })}
            
          </ScrollView> 
         
          </View>
Styles:
headerMargin:{
   flexDirection:"row",
  width:'100%',
   marginTop:6,
   marginBottom:5,
   height:30,
     borderColor:"#2795FF",
   borderBottomWidth:1.5,
   alignSelf:"center",
   justifyContent:"center",
   alignItems:"center",
   alignContent:"center",
   paddingBottom:5
}
```

Can anyone let me know what wrong with the code.
The above code works well in iOS but not in android.

Comment: Hello, could you provide some screenshots of your app? I've tried to reproduce your layout in snack, but I couldn't. But you can try to take out the ```<View/>``` with style ```headerMargin``` and put the style inside the ```style``` of ScrollView. If this doesn't work, it will be better with the screenshots. Waiting for your feedback. Thx :).

Comment: @GabrielMenezesdaSilva I will try adding styles to scrollview and will revert you.

Comment: @GabrielMenezesdaSilva still unable to scroll. Sorry can't share you the complete app screenshot. But  how come the same code works in iOS but not in android..Whereas it scrolls perfectly when I remove horizontal={true}

Comment: The scrollview was not working so finally achieved it using flatList.

Comment: Nice! I just would like to know why it was not working with ScrollView. Did you find out why?

Comment: @GabrielMenezesdaSilva No I struggled a lot for it .But I didn't found any solution and also the exact problem due to which it was not working. So I used flatList finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding pressable content inside.

```
<ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <Pressable>
    ... your list of items here
  </Pressable>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Straight from React Native docs, for the scroll view's children to be arranged horizontally in a row instead of vertically in a column the only prop you need to use it's `horizontal`.

```
<ScrollView horizontal>
  <Child/>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a horizontal prop to the ScrollView component like so:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true}> </ScrollView>
```

You can also use a FlatList and use the same horizontal prop on it too.